# What are the house numbers?

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, pattern

Following the last question " What is the corner house number?" here is possibly a more challenging version.

Fill in the missing house numbers on the map shown below. The area is occupied by math and language loving (crazy) residents who have come up with the interesting names.

> There are 4 streets: Ragaman, Orderly, Strongarm and Integer. Their
>   names are relevant (clues) to the answer. So please explain how.
>
> Each street will have increasing (or decreasing) house numbers. Each
>   street numbers are in a specific pattern and/or may have a unique
>   property.They are all three digit numbers.
>
> Corner houses will of course satisfy the patterns/property on both the
>   crossing streets.

[image]

Note : It may sound like incomplete info but it is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ragaman Street

> has house numbers on each block that are *anagrams*. In this case we have 102, 120, 201, 210.

Integer Street

> has house numbers that are triangular numbers. In this case we have 153, 171, 190, 210.

Strongarm Street

> has [Armstrong numbers](http://oeis.org/A005188). In this case we have 153, 370, 371, 407.

Now Orderly Street

> goes 102, ?, 305, 407. I suppose these are 1234 (positive integers) concatenated with 02 03 05 07 (prime numbers), so the final number is 203.

Comment: Can you explain the link between `Integer Street` and the type of numbers?

Comment: Er, dunno :-). Maybe because the $n$th triangular number = the sum of the first $n$ positive integers?